# Need help converting C Mersenne twister implementation to be useful to me

Tags: c, random, implementation, mersenne-twister

I am using [this](http://en.literateprograms.org/Mersenne_twister_%28C%29) implementation of the Mersenne twister for a diamond-square terrain generator I am writing. The point of using a separate implementation rather than the built in rand() is that I want the same seed to generate the same map every time. Diamond-square requires a random error to be added on to every pixel, so I need to generate many, many random numbers from a single seed. Mersenne twister would be good for this, but as far as I can tell, this implementation generates only one random number. I have replaced the rand() in mt_init() with an integer argument. I can make no further head or tail of the code, however, so I must turn to you to ask: what steps should I take so that mt_random(n) returns the nth random number in the Mersenne twister series it belts out?

Comment: I don't think that you are using the code correctly. PRNGs generally return the *next* value on each call, the argument (if present is for *scaling*).

Comment: Why not just use `srand` with `rand` to set the seed and get a repeatable pseudo random sequence that way ?

Comment: @Paul R: Perhaps the OP wants the sequence to be repeatable across different C implementations.

Comment: @caf: good point - that would make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need more random numbers, just keep calling `mt_random` as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would reconsider using `rand` and `srand`. If you want a separate random function whose state isn't affected by normal calls to `rand`, you can use something like this.

```
unsigned int my_seed = 42;

int my_rand()
{
    srand(my_seed);
    return my_seed = rand();
}
```